# Run npm start command inside docker in background

Tags: node.js, reactjs, docker, npm

I have a docker container containing React app created by `create-react-app`.

On the start of container I want to run npm start command and get back to my host terminal. Right now it is still showing the react development server stdout

```
docker exec web bash -c "cd web; npm install; nohup npm start &"
```

Comment: -d detached mode

Comment: I'd usually run `npm install` in my Dockerfile; as a general rule you don't install software in a running container (it will be lost as soon as the container is deleted).

Comment: The reason I am not running in docker file is because I am using mount volumes in `docker-compose`. By the time it tries to run the CMD the volume is not mounted yet. Can you please tell how can I make sure the volume is mounted first. That will solve my problem then.

Comment: @xadm It doesnn't work this way

Comment: use portainer - far easier to manage docker containers